# Zend render radio wtih adjacent label

Tags: forms, zend-framework

Currently working on Zend 1.13. By default the radio input control is initiated as follows:

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'q1rating', array(
    'multiOptions'  =>  array(5),
    'label'         => 'Question 1'
));
```

And is wrapped into its label as such:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="q1rating" id="q1rating-1" value="1" />5</label>
```

How would I have to initiate the control to get the radio input be adjacent to its label and not wrapped into it:

```
<label>5</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1rating" id="q1rating-1" value="1" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is hard-coded into the `formRadio` helper, so the only way to change it would be override that helper, and get the form element to use your version instead. Doing this would also make the label non-clickable. If you're doing this just to aid styling of the form, I'd see if you can achieve what you want with CSS instead.

Comment: Actually was able to pinpoint the hardcoded part for radio buttons. What I am actually trying to achieve is purely CSS-based (pure CSS star rating).

Comment: Any info (or better yet, a sample) on a custom view helper for radio buttons?